# How to target HTML tags inside carousel

Tags: html, css, frontend, bootstrap-vue

I have a quick question about [BootstrapVue carousel](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/carousel):

How can I target the HTML tag inside the `b-carousel-slide` component to change things like font size and so on?

I know that you can change the HTML tag by using the `text-tag` prop (see my code example).

Would be great if this one's easy to solve or at least someone points me to the respective section in the documentation.

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <b-carousel
      id="carousel"
      :interval="3000"
      controls
      fade
      indicators
      background="#ababab"
      img-width="1024"
      img-height="480"
    >
      <b-carousel-slide
        v-for="item in services"
        :key="item.title"
        :caption="item.title"
        :text="item.description"
        text-tag="p"
        :img-src="require(`../assets/images/${item.image}`)"
      ></b-carousel-slide>
    </b-carousel>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Carousel',
    data() {
      return {
        services: [
          {
            title: 'Title',
            description:
              'Text',
            image: 'picture.jpg',
          },
          {
            title: 'Title',
            description: `Text`,
            image: 'picture.jpg',
          },
          {
            title: 'Title',
            description: `Text`,
            image: 'picture.jpg',
          },
          {
            title: 'Title',
            description: `Text`,
            image: 'picture.jpg',
          },
        ],
      };
    },
  };
</script>

<style scoped>
  p {
    color: 'red';
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're facing is trying to target a sub-component inside a scoped style tag.

To do this, you will need to use [deep selectors](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors).

Either of these should work.

```css
<style scoped>
  /deep/ p {
    color: 'red';
  }

  >>> p {
    color: 'red';
  }

  ::v-deep p {
    color: 'red';
  }
</style>
```